Error 403 when receiving server information
import requests
import cloudscraper
import json

scraper = cloudscraper.create_scraper()
ApiKey = "xxx"

try:
    response = scraper.get("https://game.whynodes.space/api/client", headers={
        'method': 'GET',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'content-type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer' + ApiKey
    })

    if response.status_code == 200:
        try:
            api_response = response.json()

            object_type = api_response.get("object")

            print(object_type)
        
        except json.JSONDecodeError:
            print("Ответ сервера не является валидным JSON")
    
    else:
        print("Произошла ошибка при выполнении запроса. Код ошибки:", response.status_code)

except Exception as e:
    print("Произошла ошибка:", e)

prints
Произошла ошибка при выполнении запроса. Код ошибки: 403


You're missing a space after Bearer in the header
